# Can this question be on topic in the Workplace?

Tags: discussion

I've come across the following question: [Working with anxiety](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/152601/working-with-anxiety)
It seems to me, that this question as it stands has nothing to do with anything we could answer here, as it basically is asking if it is ok to take medication for anxiety or if OP could become an addict. Is there any way this question could be formulated to make it on topic or alternatively a place in the Stack Exchange network where it could be migrated to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've closed this because topic aside it's essentially asking "what do you recommend for me?". As commented I see a potential on-topic question concerning the (long-term) use of "performance enhancers" (regardless of reason) in a workplace context, but that's not really what the OP is asking about. In its current form it's also just way too long and unfocused as a question.